# C login program in terminal, having some problems with the Input-Output

Tags: c, authentication

I have tried to put together this basic login system as a bit of practice. My issue is that when you run the .exe file straight from the folder, the registration part does not get past the first name. I am wondering if anyone can point me towards the problem? The worst part is that I can't seem to make sense of the problems that return in the console. I'll post the output from code runner beneath the code.

*Here's the code:*

````
#include <stdio.h>

struct login {
    char fName;
    char lName;
    char userName;
    char passWord;

};

registe()
{
    FILE *log;
    log=fopen("login.txt", "w");
    struct login l;

    printf("Enter your first name: ");scanf("%s", l.fName);
    printf("Enter your last name: ");scanf("%s", l.lName);
    printf("Enter your username: ");scanf("%s", l.userName);
    printf("Enter your password: ");scanf("%s", l.passWord);
    fwrite(&l, sizeof(l),1,log);

    fclose(log);

    printf("\n\nyour username is UserID\n");
    printf("Now login with your UserID and password");
    printf("\nPress any key to continue...");
    getch();
    system("CLS");
    login();  
}

login()
{
    char userName[200], passWord[20];
    FILE *log;
    log=fopen("login.txt", "r");
    struct login l;
    printf("UserID: ");
    scanf("%s", &userName);
    printf("Password: ");
    scanf("%s", &passWord);

    while(fread(&l,sizeof(l), 1, log))
    {
        if(strcmp(userName,l.userName)==0 && strcmp(passWord,l.passWord)==0)
        {
             printf("successful login\n!");
        }
        else {
            printf("please enter the correct credentials");
        }
    }
    fclose(log);

}

int main() 
{
    int cho;

    printf("Press '1' for registration \nPress 2 for login\n\n");
    scanf("/n%d ", &cho);
    if(cho == 1)
    {
        system("CLS");
        registe();
    }

    else if (cho ==2)
    {
        system("CLS");
        login();
    }

}```




>PS C:\Comp-Sci Year1\Newworkspace> cd "c:" ; if ($?) { gcc tempCodeRunnerFile.c -o tempCodeRunnerFile } ; if ($?) { .\tempCodeRunnerFile }
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:11:1: warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
   11 | registe()
      | ^~~~~~~
tempCodeRunnerFile.c: In function 'registe':
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:28:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'getch'; 
did you mean 'getc'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   28 |     getch();
      |     ^~~~~
      |     getc
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:29:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'system' 
[-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   29 |     system("CLS");
      |     ^~~~~~
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:30:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'login' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   30 |     login();
      |     ^~~~~
tempCodeRunnerFile.c: At top level:
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:33:1: warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
   33 | login()
      | ^~~~~
tempCodeRunnerFile.c: In function 'login':
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:46:12: warning: implicit declaration of function 'strcmp' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   46 |         if(strcmp(userName,l.userName)==0 && strcmp(passWord,l.passWord)==0)
      |            ^~~~~~
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:46:29: warning: passing argument 2 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   46 |         if(strcmp(userName,l.userName)==0 && strcmp(passWord,l.passWord)==0)
      |                            ~^~~~~~~~~
      |                             |
      |                             char
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:46:29: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'char'
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:46:63: warning: passing argument 2 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   46 |         if(strcmp(userName,l.userName)==0 && strcmp(passWord,l.passWord)==0)
      |                                                              ~^~~~~~~~~
      |                                                               |
      |                                                               char
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:46:63: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'char'
*Press '1' for registration 
Press 2 for login*
````

Comment: The problem is you use an *Unformatted* write to `login.txt` in `registe()` and then attempt a *Formatted* read in `login()` -- that won't work. Choose one or the other. Either write all 4 members of your struct as single lines in `registe()` or read a struct at-a-time with `fread` in `login()` (I would suggest the former) Avoid `getch()` unless a non-cannonical read is necessary (it isn't just to hold the terminal open on windows), use `getchar()` instead (or include the archaic DOS header `conio.h`)

Comment: Um, most of those warnings are really, really important and your program has undefined behavior most likely.  Please read an introductory book on programming C.  You must learn what a string is and how to use it before you write this much code.  As a beginner, you should make your compiler treat all warnings as errors, which will force you to fix them.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for the answer. I'm having trouble with the difference between formatted and non formatted read and write. What is the difference and which parts need to change? Thanks again, I'll change getch out for getchar also.

Comment: Just understand `fwrite` is an unformatted write. Especially when writing `structs` it may include padding bytes between struct members and the C-standard doesn't define where those go (so different compilers are free to do it differently). For formatted writes you can use `fprintf` (or `fputs` if no conversions are required) to write a line-at-a-time to your file. Then when you go to read the structs back in, you would loop reading 4-lines per-iteration into one-struct. If you keep `fwrite`, then you will need to loop `while (fread (&l, sizeof l, 1, log) > 0)`  to read a struct at-a-time.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Okay, thank you. I'm making the change. I am now receiving issues with other parts of the code. Namely: login L

incomplete type not allowed wherever l is used.  "struct login l;" for example

Comment: All you can do is take the warnings one at a time. As noted by others, the write and read is just one of the logic and syntax problems you have. The rule is, always compile with full warnings enabled -- and don't accept code until it compiles without warning.  If you note all the `"implicit declaration"` warnings -- those are telling you you haven't included the proper headers to allow the compiler to find those functions. For instance, `strcmp()` is provided in `string.h`. Just take them one-by-one and listen to what the compiler is telling you (they are quite good now days)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks a lot for your time, I'll get working through each warning